# SCSS Nested Ancestors

Tags: css, sass

Please see my comment inside my SCSS code.

Is this kind of deeper nesting possible in SASS yet? I'm sure I found a solution I was happy with years ago, but I have forgotten it. Can someone help shed some light on how I might go about this kind of nesting.

**SCSS**

```
.class {
    color: red;

    &__nested {
        color: green;
    }

    &__link {
        color: yellow;

        &:hover {
            border: 1px solid yellow;

            ^^&__nested { // Is something like this one possible?
                color: pink;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Compiled**

```
.class {
    color: red;
}

.class__nested {
    color: green;
}

.class__link {
    color: yellow;
}

.class__link:hover {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.class__link:hover .class__nested { // Is something like this one possible?
    color: pink;
}
```

**I do not want to have to define a variable as such.**

```
.class {
    $parent: .class;

    &__link {
        color: yellow;

        &:hover {
            border: 1px solid yellow;

            #{$parent}__nested {
                color: pink;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you hover-over `.class__link`, you want `.class__nested` to turn pink?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Cool, one min to type an answer

Comment: I don't think it is possible without a variable holding the parent reference. By the way, you can store the ampersand `&` directly instead of rewriting the name.

Comment: Could be a possibility I guess. I am currently looking at changing my gulp workflow to PostCSS but I'm loosing some functionality like @functions, so I am in 2 minds atm... Because PostCSS has a plugin called nested-ancestors which is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You said no variable like ".class", but if you're just trying to avoid strongly typing it and nothing is stopping you from actually using a variable, you can do `&` like:

```css
.class {
  $self: &;

  color: red;

  &__link {
    color: yellow;
  }

  &__nested {
    color: green;

    &:hover + #{ $self }__link {
      color: pink;
    }  
  }
}
```

JSFiddle of working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gy3zLqsm/

Comment: It is no what OP asked for. You changed the class names.

Comment: Was just about to say the same thing. I am using a BEM naming convention and although what you've written is correct it doesn't solve my problem of using ampersands to include partial class names based upon the parent.

Comment: Ah, whoops. Sorry! @KINKWILDE you say you don't want a variable like `$parent: .class`. Are you only trying to avoid static-typing, or does that also include `$self: &`? I have a working copy with that

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid having to do it all together. There is a PostCSS plugin called nested-ancestors which allows me to do exactly what I've written above, but I wondered if it's possible to do it in SASS yet... I ideally don't want to move my workflow from SASS because I loose functionality.

Comment: The `$self: &;` method works well and allows OP to solve their problem. This should be the accepted answer.